# What is considered an incredible feat the for the "Jack of All Trades" commendations

Tags: halo-reach

For the Halo:Reach multiplayer commendation, "Jack of All Trades," what is considered an incredible feat?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Perform an incredible feat in Multiplayer Matchmaking." Incredible feats in matchmaking are akin to earning medals that are not categorized under any other commendation. These medals include (but not limited to?):

- **Protector** (Save a teammate by killing his foe)
- **Avenger** (Avenge a teammate's dath)
- **Revenge** (Kill the opponent responsible for your death)
- **Show Stopper** (Kill an opponent while they are performing an assassination)
- **Yoink** (Kill an enemy player while they are being assassinated)
- **Close Call** (Kill an opponent while you are weakened and without a shield. Survive)
- **Rejection** (Active Armor Lock and survive massive damage)
- **Extermination** ( Killing the last alive player on the opposing team with at least an Overkill that results in the entire team being dead at once)

[Source](http://halo.wikia.com/wiki/Jack_of_All_Trades)